# Permanent of a matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, permanent

Let $n \geq 2$ $a,b$ complex numbers (or in some other ring if you wish).
What is the permanent of the matrix
$$M(a,b,n)=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a & a & a & ... & a & a \\
    a & b & b & ... & b & b \\
    a & a & b & ... & b & b \\
    ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
    a & a & a & ... & a & b
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
I have no experience with permanents but it seems that the result can be expressed in an infinite sum at least for special values of $a$ and $b$.
Examples (conjectured):

-$M(1,2,n)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{k^n}{2^{k+1}}}$ (see the answer of [Permanent of Nakayama algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279753/permanent-of-nakayama-algebras/279782#279782) for a motivation for this)

-$M(2,3,n)=$ https://oeis.org/A004123

-$M(1,4,n)$=https://oeis.org/A255927

(you can find sequences in the oeis for some other values too)

Maybe there is even a combinatorial interpretation of such results?

Comment: A possible approach: There is an identity that relates the permanent of $A+B$ to the permanents of submatrices of $A$ and $B$ (see, for instance, this paper http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081088708817770 ).  By writing your matrix as $aJ+B$ where $J$ is the all-ones matrix, this identity leaves you the following problem: calculate the permanent of your matrix, and its submatrices, in the case $a=0$.

Comment: $M(a, b, n)$ is $a^n$ times the generating polynomial for the number of exceedances http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000155 (in $b$).

Comment: More precisely: take out a factor $a$ from each row, move your first row last, then compute the permanent from its definition.

Comment: @MartinRubey thanks, does this explain the infinite sum identities?

Comment: The formulas should now follow from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Identities, very likely the first one.  Note the exceedances and ascents have the same distribution via the so-called first fundamental transformation, http://www.findstat.org/MapsDatabase/Mp00087.

Comment: Thanks to the help/suggestions of Martin Rubey a proof has now been found. I might post it soon.